# Checkbox disable few select on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-select

Hello I have dynamicaly generated table with checkboxes and selects.
Now I want to disable/enable selects on checkbox change.

I look for scirpts for it, but everything I found don't work for me.

here is my code:

```
<script>
            function toggleSelection(e){
                var el = '#tsh' + e;
                var el1 = '#tsm' + e;
                var el2 = '#teh' + e;
                var el3 = '#tem' + e;
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(el).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(el1).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(el2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(el3).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $(el).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(el1).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(el2).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $(el3).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        </script>
        <tr class="form-group">
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="{value}" id="dc{value}" onchange="toggleSelection('{value}')" {chk}> {name}</label></td>
            <td><select id="tsh{value}" class="form-control" {dis} name="tsh{value}" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="tsm{value}" class="form-control" {dis} name="tsm{value}" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="teh{value}" class="form-control" {dis} name="teh{value}" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
            </select></td>
            <td><select id="tem{value}" class="form-control" {dis} name="tem{value}" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%">
            </select></td>
        </tr>
```

Of course there are options between selects. Tis code works but only one way its enable selects but don't want to disable them.

Comment: You have some invalid html here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do this:

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('select').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Db7F/)

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
$( yourElement ).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a simple example to demonstrate how you can enable/disable select element based on whether or not your checkbox is checked.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on('change', function(){
         $("select").prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/Rg9cM/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.form-group input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.form-group select').attr('disabled', true);

    } else {

        $('.form-group select').attr('disabled', false);
    }

})
```